# How to get hashtag with all accentued letters, digits but without ".,;" and other ponctuations signs

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

How to get hashtag with all accentued letters, digits but without ".,;" and other ponctuations signs...

For the moment, /#(\S*)/ig is the best JS regex I ve found but the hashtag keeps the , (or .) just after. I do not want

INPUT:
 #Bonjour, #éopë

OUTPUT:
 #Bonjour #éopë

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Using the regular expression `A-zÀ-ÿ` will capture any letters including accented letters, then just add in space and #.

- `[^]` -- anything that's not in the array brackets
- `A-zÀ-ÿ` -- accented characters
- -- space
- `\#` -- hash

```js
const input = '#Bonjour, #éopë'
console.log(input.replace(/[^A-zÀ-ÿ \#]+/gmi, ''))
```

Comment: You regexp is a bit lazy: `A-z` matches `[ ] /` etc, `À-ÿ` does not match  "accented" chars behind `\u00FF` (and also matches two non-letters).

Comment: Thanks but if on https://regex101.com/ you put #(\S*) /ig and, in test string : #Bonjour, #éopë you see that the "," is taken. Now with your regex /[^A-zÀ-ÿ \#]+/gmi, '')) all is selected. My focus is to get like /[^A-zÀ-ÿ \#]+/gmi, '')) without ","